# How to read / query SQL table after creating an 'Engine' object in Python?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlclient, database-cursor

I'm using Python 3.7, I'm not very familiar with SQL with Python, I have the code below to create a SQL engine:

```
mysql_engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql://xxxxxx')
```

Then I have a pre-defined SQL query, here's a simplified version: (this query I have tested in MySQL Workbench and it works fine)

```
example_query = '''
select
    a.date
from
    abc.xyz a
'''
```

I want to be able to read/query from the table, I tried:

```
cursor = mysql_engine.cursor()
cursor.execute(example_query)
```

but I got error `AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'cursor'`, perhaps I can use `pandas`? Can someone help with this, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `pd.read_sql`

The second argument can accept a sqlalchemy engine.

From the [Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html)

> **con**: SQLAlchemy connectable, str, or sqlite3 connection Using SQLAlchemy
> makes it possible to use any DB supported by that library. If a DBAPI2
> object, only sqlite3 is supported. The user is responsible for engine
> disposal and connection closure for the SQLAlchemy connectable; str
> connections are closed automatically.

```
pd.read_sql(example_query, mysql_engine)
```

Comment: Hi I had a try but I got an error: `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'aws-rds-instance-endpoint-name' (10060)")
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)`

Comment: That's a connection error.  Possibly with your connection string.  And I wouldn't be able to help with that.  What I posted answers your original question though.  Once you have a working engine, the use of `pd.read_sql` does the rest of the work for you.

Comment: Does anyone know how to make sure the mysql_engine closes after completion? Does it occur automatically or need it be explicit?

Comment: @Lisle [this page has the information you need](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html) In short, if you want to make sure your connection is closed, you should take care to close it.